# PHP Exec command works intermittently

Tags: php, exec, args

I have been running the following command line and has been working fine.  Then without warning it has stopped and failes to execute.

```
exec("$path_to_php $emailer $digest_sub_security_var \"$vid_menu\" \"$image_menu\" \"$article_menu\" $media_query_lmt_v $media_query_lmt_i $media_query_lmt_a > /dev/null &");
```

I think (but can not be sure) that it's something to do with the following `\"$vid_menu\" \"$image_menu\" \"$article_menu\"`

These items are image thumnails, titles, descptions in text and urls

How can I get the command line to work consistently.

Answer (score 0):

Try to log your application when it is running for understading the problem.

Comment: Im very new to programming.  ow do I go about logging?